# How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document in Mongolian?

Tags: texlive

I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mongolian]{babel}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
Монголоор бичье
\end{document}
```

but it doesn't work.

I have downloaded all fonts with this command `sudo getnonfreefonts-sys -a` and `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

I use tex-live on ubuntu.

How to set font to Arial throughout the entire document in Mongolian?

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your document work with LaTeX, you should use:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mongolian,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{uarial}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
Монголоор бичье
\end{document}
```

It will use the default sans serif font, unless you uncomment `\usepackage{uarial}` (but I do not have it, so it was impossible for me to test it). If it still doesn't work when you set `uarial`, it means the font does not contain cyrillic characters, and that you should probably use XeLaTeX with an arial font that has a cyrillic set. XeLaTeX allows you to use system fonts directly, using their names.

In that case, you would need:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[mongolian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
Монголоор бичье
\end{document}
```

Replace `\setmainfont{Arial Unicode MS}` with another arial font that you have on your system and that includes cyrillic characters.